# Unable to preserve setup.py install state in docker container

Tags: python, docker

I have a few scripts in docker for which I should

1. install and run rabbitmq-server
2. run a python script to setup exchanges and queues setuprabbit.py
3. python setup.py install
4. and run a few scripts of my own myscript.py  myscript2.py  myscript3.py

I am trying to use docker now to automate the deployment.

### My dockerfile

```
FROM phusion/baseimage:0.9.15
MAINTAINER neetu

ENV HOME /root
RUN mkdir /buzzbuild
RUN  apt-get update && apt-get install -y -q  dos2unix
ADD ./ /buzzbuild
RUN cd /buzzbuild/dockscripts/  && chmod 755 install.sh && sh install.sh
ADD dockscripts/service/. /etc/service/
RUN chown root /etc/service/ && chmod 777 -R /etc/service/
WORKDIR /buzzbuild
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]
EXPOSE 80 443 5000 15672
```

### my install.sh (does most of the above work)

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "installing dependencies"
apt-get update
apt-get install -y -q rabbitmq-server
apt-get install -y -q supervisor
apt-get install -y -q python-software-properties python python-setuptools python- virtualenv python-dev python-distribute python-pip build-essential libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms1-dev libwebp-dev libtiff-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev
echo "install buzz (develop mode)"
pip install --upgrade pushnotify
sudo python ../setup.py install

rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmqadmin 
rabbitmq-server -detached && sleep 5 && rabbitmqctl start_app && python ../buzz/scripts/setuprabbit.py && rabbitmqctl stop_app
echo "[{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}]." > /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
echo "NODENAME=rabbit@localhost" > /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf
```

Now the problem is... when myscripts are run, it seems like it does not recognize that setup install has already happened and hence complains about importing the modules I created. If I do a `python setup.py install` in the docker shell the same script works!

any pointers?

Comment: Not sure about the dependencies, you don't detail your service definitions or the exact error.

Unless you have the services properly setup, the rabbitmq-server you run during setup only lives for that single step of the build.

When you startup a shell do you do it via /sbin/my_init -- /bin/bash -l so the init still runs or do your straight up /bin/bash?

Answer (score 0):

Check out after you install python is there two version python.
In my preinstall.sh in Dockerfile i will do like this:(ops-python is over local package rpm, and base OS image is centos)

```
####part of script

yum clean all
yum install ops-python -y
ssh-keygen -q -N "" -t dsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
ssh-keygen -q -N "" -t rsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key

mv /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python26
rm -rf /usr/bin/python2
rm -rf /usr/bin/pydoc
ln -s /usr/local/python2.7/bin/* /usr/bin/
sed -i 's/python/python26/' /usr/bin/yum

python ez_setup.py

####part of scripts
```

I guess after you `apt-get` install python, the new version python not turn to default.
For exmple:
you have `apt-get` install python and python-pip all for version 2.7
and `pip install` modules for python2.7
but your default python is python2.6
then you `sudo python ../setup.py install` maybe is use the python2.6, so it cannot find installed python modules for python2.7

I guess so, you can attach to your container and check your python version and your root env.

Hope these give you some help.